# I have a contract and I don't know how to call the function

Tags: contract-development

[image: Mint Button]

[image: ABI]

[![Contract][3]][3]

The "Mint Button[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgD9v.png)" I have calls the function from the ABI but I don't know what the parameters are meant to be I have attached the "Contract[3]" as well for the code to limit the amount of mints. I want the function called to send the required amount of NFTs to the account which the value is whatever up to 10. [ABI]

```
function safeMint(address to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    require(totalSupply() < MAX_SUPPLY, "Cannot Mint more");
    require(msg.value >= mintRate, "Not enough Ether sent.");
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount, "Max Minted");
    require(msg.value >= mintRate * _mintAmount);
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    _safeMint(to, tokenId);

    for(uint i = 0; i < _mintAmount; i++){
        uint supply = totalSupply();
        safeMint( msg.sender, supply);
        }
        
}
```

Comment: Please include the cotract as source so it is easier to test.

Comment: I have added it just now

Answer (score 0):

Try `contract.safeMint(account, mintAmount, {from: account, value: COST})`. You also forgot to add the `mintAmount` parameter. You can find more details about this here https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts.html

Comment: I read the web.js docs about .send() function however I still cannot resolve it. I have added the ABI maybe something from there. The mintAmount should be a variable that I want to add, The function doesn't even call anymore.